# How to add car models in brand

Tags: android

Here is my problem :

I want to add some car related to his brand like :

CADILLAC : CTS, SRX, ESCALADE.

CHEVROLET : CAMARA, CORVETTE, VOLT.

I want to select a brand of vehicule and access to model name into Textview like :

```
                                CADILLAC

         -CTS
         -SRX
         -...
```

What should i use ?
Array ?

Thanks for response

EDIT : here is my actual code, it' snot for brand and models but it was more easier to explain like that...

```
try
{

    JSONArray QCM = response.getJSONArray("QCM");

    for (int i = 0; i < QCM.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject getQcmObject = QCM.getJSONObject(i);

        //Récupère la question et la place dans un array
        String questionGet = getQcmObject.getString("question");
        questionArray.add(questionGet);

        //Récupère les choix de la quesiton
        JSONArray choiceGet = getQcmObject.getJSONArray("choix");

        //Boucle qui permet d'ajouter les choix dans une listes
        for (int x = 0; x < choiceGet.length(); x++) {
            String choice = choiceGet.getString(x);
            listOfChoice.add(choice);
            System.out.println(listOfChoice);
        }
        multiMap.put(questionGet, listOfChoice);
        listOfChoice.clear();


    }
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> setMap = multiMap.entrySet();
    // Get an iterator
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,  ArrayList<String>>> iteratorMap = setMap.iterator();
    System.out.println("\nHashMap with Multiple Values");
    // display all the elements
    while(iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry =
                (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>) iteratorMap.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Key = '" + key + "' has values: " + values);
    }
}
```

I can't get acess to value ! here is my log cat

```
    05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Combien d'os contient le squelette humain?' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Quel est la couleur du cheval blanc d'Henri IV?' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Une hernie inguinale étranglée :' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Lors des traumatismes de l'abdomen, le viscère le plus souvent touché est:' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Quelles sont les normes de la glycémie pré-pondial?' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Pathologies psychiatriques' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'En fonction de l'agent vulnérant, les brûlures sont classées en quatre groupes. Lesquels?' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Dans le bilan pré-thérapeutique du cancer de l'endomètre, l'exploration la plus performante est:' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Dans la péritonite généralisée d'origine appendiculaire, lequel de ces signes est toujours absent?' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Les complications immédiates des brûlures électriques sont:' has values: []
05-10 11:50:34.223 23881-23881/lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo I/System.out: Key = 'Les myomes ont un effet délétère sur les paramètres de fertilité, s'ils sont:' has values: []
```

Comment: first, you need to create `Multimap<String,String> cars` not `Multimap<String, List<String>> cars`. Secondly, you don't have to create temrary `listOfChoice` list and put the models with the same (brand) key: `multiMap.put(questionGet, choice);`

Comment: When i do that, i have only one model in my brand

Comment: Yeah, some weird behavior of `entrySet`. this code works well:
`for(String brand : cars.keySet()) {
    for (String model : cars.get(brand)) {
        System.out.println("Key = '" + brand + "' has values: " + model);
    }
}`

Comment: for what should i replace brand in  "for (String model : cars.get(brand))" ?? :)

Comment: you shouldn't, I just named it so. my point is that you shouldn't use `multiMap.entrySet()` and iterate it with `cars.keySet()`

Comment: Oh okay i see ! but in  for (String model : cars.get(brand)) the error say

foreach no applicable to type String

Comment: because you need to change `Multimap<String, List<String>>` to `Multimap<String, String> cars` (don't use the list)

Comment: Ah, right. show me please how exactly you declare `multiMap`

Comment: Multimap<String, String> multiMap; like that ^^

Comment: but it's ok but when i launch app i get Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.common.collect.Multimap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Oh it's working ! i just declare like u said ^^ 
Multimap<String,String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google-guava's multimap.

```
Multimap<String,String> cars = ArrayListMultimap.create();
cars.put("CADILLAC", "CTS");
cars.put("CADILLAC", "SRX");
cars.put("CADILLAC", "ESCALADE");
cars.put("CHEVROLET", "CAMARO");
cars.put("CHEVROLET", "CORVETTE");
cars.put("CHEVROLET", "VOLT");
```

here is the link https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap

Comment: Very interesting, i think it's what i want !

Comment: @FriedrichDylan great! if you really like the answer, it's nice to vote up for it.  If you think the answer solves your question you should accept it. so I can earn my karma, thanks)

Comment: I'm back, i finally understand how it's work ! it's really cool but just a question, how can i acess them now ?

Comment: `cars.get("CADILLAC")` returns a list of the models, `cars.keySet()` returns a set with the brands

Comment: Did i can get the brand with a int ? i tried but i won't work :(

Comment: If you really need so you can use `Iterables.get(cars.keySet(), 1)`

Comment: Can't get my value for models when i get brand, i update my question with actual code

Answer (score 0):

Why not one ArrayList  listOfBrand.

And each car:

```
public class Car{

Brand carBrand;
String carName;
}

public class Brand{

String brandName;
ArrayList<Car> listOfCar;
}
```